# gzip response for a single route

Tags: node.js, azure, express, azure-web-app-service

I ma using express and compression library:

```
var compression = require('compression')
var express = require('express')

var app = express()

// compress all requests
app.use(compression())
```

**Question:**

1. How can I just add a gzip response for a single route?

   2. If may server is IIS 8 which is host at Azure web app, will compression work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. How can I just add a gzip response for a single route?

You can inline it, as with any other middleware:

```
app.get('/route', compression([OPTIONS]), function(req, res) {
  ...
});
```

Be aware that the `compression` middleware maintains a default threshold of 1KB of data, below which responses won't be compressed. See [the documentation](https://github.com/expressjs/compression#threshold) on how to change this if required.

> 2. If may server is IIS 8 which is host at Azure web app, will compression work?

I would assume so, but can't state definitively as I don't have any IIS/Azure experience. But why not try it out?

Answer (score 2):

`gzip` is a default operation on IIS server on Azure Web Apps. You can simply create a default node.js application on Azure Web Apps, and directly visit the endpoint of your site, you can check the response header and find such like following:

[image]